# topological sorting using dfs

Tags: c++, graph-theory, depth-first-search

here is topological sorting using DFS in c++,which has bugs(out of bound error)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int count=0;
 static int *a=new int[8];

void dfs(int u,bool v[],bool matrix[][8])
{
    v[u]=true;
    for(int  i=0;i<8;i++)
        if(!v[i]&& matrix[u][i])
            dfs(i,v,matrix);

    a[count++]=u;
}

int main()
{
    bool v[8];
    bool matrix[8][8];
    matrix[7][6]=true;
    matrix[0][1];
    matrix[1][2]=true;
    matrix[2][3]=true;
    matrix[3][4]=true;
    matrix[2][5]=true;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        if(!v[i])
            dfs(i,v,matrix);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    cout<<a[7-i]<<"  ";
}
```

please help me to fix  this error,i think i should create matrix[8][2],but how to continue after that?

Comment: Here's one candidate for an out of range access `a[count++]=u;`. How do you know that `count` is *always* in range during the recursive calls?

Comment: What error are you experiencing?  Is it related to the fact that many elements in `v` and `matrix` are uninitialized?

Comment: @BoPersson - the condition on calling `dfs` is that `v[i]` is `false`.  There are only 8 elements in `v` and the current one is set to `false` immediately in `dfs`, so I don't think there will be overindexing due to recursion.

Comment: What error do you get exactly ? do you get a segmentation fault ? there is no such things as out of bound error with c arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a few changes and now your program finishes successfully on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ALUiL)
The most significant change is that you did not initialize matrix and v(even without this change the program still finished successfully but the output was only 0-s). I did not see the error you are talking about. The reason for getting only 0-s when you did not initialize v is obvious - all the values where non-zero and so all nodes where considered not visited.

EDIT: I also changed line 27 where you seemed to have forgotten " = true;"

EDIT 2: you are not freeing the memory for a which is not good. Also I don't see why you need dynamic array for a. You know its size aforehand. And one last remark - if you make the arrays matrix and v global they will get zeroed automatically(I am not saying that this is good approach just pointing out), but as they are local they are not zeroed.